# How to store and retrieve mathematical expressions to/from SQL Server database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, math, expression

How to store and retrieve mathematical expressions from SQL Server database? I am copying these formulas from ms word and using rich textbox in winforms in c# code to store it from where I want to push those in SQL Server database and pull it back to show in ASP.NET web application. Any thoughts???

Comment: How is this any different from text?

Comment: How do you store integration, square root and various mathematical signs into a database is precisely what I am looking for. Or you can take it like say you have a line of text with a mathematical expression (a^2 + b^2) in it as a image and now How would I store this in database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well this was long pending post and I almost forgot to put in the answer. It was simple I used RichTextBox and its .Rtf property to achieve this.